# How to properly move /home from separate partition into / partition?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, disk, lvm

I have two logical volume which one is used for / and another one for /home. The thing is now I want to have /home to be not separated from the /. I want to use the logical volume which I use for / to contain /home too.

How should I do this?